# Select option not working in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

The following code works fine in IE 7 and IE 6, but not in IE 8:

```
value = $("#ctl00_ContentApplication_cmbLocation option[text='" 
          + $('#ctl00_ContentApplication_lblResLocation').text() + "']").val();
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you mean `:contains(...)` instead of `[text=...]`?

Try:

```
value = $("#ctl00_ContentApplication_cmbLocation option:contains('"+ $( '#ctl00_ContentApplication_lblResLocation' ).text() +"')").val();
```

For example, `$('option:contains('text')` will match `<option value='val'>text</option>` (but also `<option value='val'>text and some more words</option>`).

Answer (score 0):

These are ID from asp.net, the best way to detect it in jQuery is:

```
var div1 = $('[id$=cmbLocation]');
var div2 = $('[id$=lblResLocation]');
```

try and let me know.